# Problems with migrating a WooCommerce orders

Tags: plugins, migration, e-commerce

I am trying to import/export orders from one WooCommerce website to another. After using the WordPress import/export tool for the "orders", the individual order page no longer shows the product(s) that were ordered for each invoice. When I view an individual order, the "Order Items" box is empty. Is there a way to fix this? Here is an image to show what I am talking about.

http://support.woothemes.com/attachments/token/iddtqxsxdquthvv/?name=woocommerce.jpg

Comment: You might want to try http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/woocommerce-exporter/ but I read that exporting orders is 'premium'

Comment: Did you resolve this? I am having similar issues importing woocommerce 1.x orders into woocommerce 2.x

Answer (score 4):

Since WooCommerce orders and products are actually custom post types, using that importing tool will only transfer limited amount of data.

To transfer the order details as well, you need to use phpMyAdmin to import the following two tables to your new site's database

- wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta
- wp_woocommerce_order_items

Answer (score 0):

You can try to move your orders automatically using `cart2cart`. The process of migration is quite easy. You simply have to follow a step by step instruction. You will also have a possibility match order statuses, so they were the same as on your current store. Here are [details](http://www.shopping-cart-migration.com/shopping-cart-migration-options/6714-woocommerce-to-woocommerce-migration). Nonetheless, it is a commercial tool but probably exactly what you are looking for.

All in all, you can try free demo migration to see how it works.

Answer (score -1):

Add this code in your child `function.php`

```
add_filter ( 'wc_order_is_editable', 'majemedia_add_order_statuses_to_editable' );

function majemedia_add_order_statuses_to_editable () {
    return TRUE;
    }
```

now you can edit orders... try editing orders and let know if any issues

Comment: What does it have to do with import and export?